# my execv() function not working in linux ubuntu

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu-14.04, execv

I wrote the following code but I always get the output: "ERROR!" (the execv function not scheduled to return)

What am I doing wrong???

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include "LineParser.h"

#define LOCATION_LEN 200
char* getL(void);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    char *loc = getL();
    char *args[] = {loc,"ls",NULL};
    int i;
    execv(args[0],args);
    printf("ERROR!");
    free(loc);
}

char* getL(void)
{
    char *buff = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char)*LOCATION_LEN);
    getcwd(buff,LOCATION_LEN);
    return buff;
}
```

Comment: First off, check errno on the return from `execv`.  Then check the parameters that you are passing.

Comment: Of course it is returning -1.  Use `errno` and `strerror` or `perror` to explain why...namely your parameters.

Comment: errno return 2
and strerror return 2

Comment: What is the real purpose and the motivation of your program? We could guess some of it wrongly!

Comment: BTW, you should remove `#include <malloc.h>`  since `malloc`  is declared from `#include <stdlib.h>`

Answer (score 3):

Read documentation of [execv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execv.3.html) and of [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and of [perror(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/perror.3.html). At the very least, you should code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *loc = getL();
  char *args[] = { loc, "ls", NULL };
  int i;
  execv(args[0], args);
  perror("execv");
  free(loc);
}
```

You should compile with `gcc -Wall -g` then use the `gdb` debugger.

Your usage of `execv` is obviously wrong (you need a full path, e.g. `"/bin/ls"`, and the order of arguments is wrong). You probably want [exevcp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execv.3.html) and you should in fact code at least:

```
  char *args = { "ls", loc, NULL };
  execvp("ls", args);
  perror("execvp")
```

If you insist on using specifically [execv(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execv.3.html) you could try

```
  char *args = { "ls", loc, NULL };
  execv("/bin/ls", args);
  perror("execv")
```

I don't understand what your code is supposed to do. You might be interested by [glob(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) & [glob(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/glob.3.html).

You probably should read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/). It seems that there are several concepts that you don't understand well enough. I guess that [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) could be useful to you (at least by running `strace ls *.c` to understand what is happening).

Maybe your `getL` is exactly what the GNU function [get_current_dir_name(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getcwd.3.html) is doing, but then the `(char**)` cast inside it is grossly wrong. And you should better clear the buffer `buff` using [memset(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memset.3.html) before calling  [getcwd(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getcwd.2.html) (and you should test against failure of ̀ malloc`and of`getcwd`)

Perhaps you want [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html), [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html), [asprintf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html), [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html); with all these, you could even avoid running `ls`

If you are coding some shell, you should `strace` some existing shell, and after having read all the references I am giving here, study the source code of [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) shells like [sash](http://members.tip.net.au/%7Edbell/programs/sash-3.8.tar.gz) and [GNU bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/)

Comment: thanks
But must use in execv so can you please explain to me how it works?
I did not understand the function parameters.

Comment: Read all the links I gave you (that should take several hours of reading). I won't try to explain what the references I gave you are explaining better than I could explain in a few minutes. And please *edit your question* to *improve it*.

Comment: I tried what you said

But it still does not work


http://www.siz.co.il/my.php?i=yme2vgnyyt1y.png

Comment: Your image show `/bin/is` (with a I lower-case)  but it should be `/bin/ls` (with an L lower-case), which is given by `which ls`

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing the correct arguments to execv. The first argument must be a path to the executable you wish to run but you are passing the path to the current working directory.

Update `getL` to return the full path to `ls`.

Comment: what is the full path to ls?

Comment: Run `which ls` in a terminal to know that. very often it is `/bin/ls`